# Projection best practices for applying ML to large scale Earth Observation imagery

Tags: coordinate-system, remote-sensing, imagery, satellite, machine-learning

I come from a data science background, rather than GIS, but work in a domain where remote-sensed imagery is widely used; so I'm still learning some of the do's & don'ts when it comes to the 'right' way to manage geospatial imagery. The answer to this question will be relevant to me more generally, but let's take this as my motivating example: I am working with optical satellite imagery to solve object detection / semantic segmentation problems using ground-truth annotations collected from countries all over the world.

I understand that no single projection system can be globally optimal, and that localised projections such as the UTM zones are available, but **my question is whether there are established 'best practices' for choosing a CRS for the imagery in each location before using it for training/inference in a machine-learning pipeline?** And to the extent that there are multiple options, what are the trade-offs to be considered for each?

Comment: what are `semantic segmentation problems`